# How to receive input from a button

Tags: python, html, flask

I have this html button

```
<input type="button" value="Setup a Automation Bot" class="setupbot" required='required' name='setupbot'>
```

And this Flask Code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os

IMAGE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'images')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = IMAGE_FOLDER



@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'disp_final.png')
    return render_template('form.html', user_image = full_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I Want that When the button is clicked some lines of code are written to an outfile

I tried many things but whenever I click the button, nothing happens.
I am quite new to Flask
Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: HTML does not trigger code execution on the server side on its own. You can follow tutorials like [this one](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-your-first-website-with-flask-part-1-903a8b44e806) to learn more about how the web works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup POST methods on any button you want to do something

For example if your button in HTML was

`<input type="submit" name="setupbot" value="Setup a Automation Bot">`

You Flask code would need to be something along the lines of

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['setupbot'] == 'Setup a Automation Bot':
            pass # do the thing
        else:
            pass # other case
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```